# release stuck hover label

Tags: safari, mouse

When I use for example a browser like Safari there are websites where you can go over an area with your mouse and a hover label appears.

[image: Safari hover label]

When I switch to fast from safari into another application or desktop the hover label just stays at it's original positions until I find the exact tab with the website where this hover label has been used.

[image: Safari hover label stuck]

How do you remove this label without having to search for the tab with the exact website in it to remove the floating label?

NOTE: I just noticed when doing a google search (dynamic suggestions) the first time it did remove the hovering label. The second time it didn't. Could this have todo with javascript?